# i forgot my pin and i'm on android 14 beta

Tags: android, google-pixel

While participating in the Android 14 beta program with my Google Pixel 6, I forgot my PIN/password. Is it advisable to perform a factory reset on my device while still enrolled in the beta program, or could it pose any risks or complications?